# Laravel permissions on nginx

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I am deploying a project to Ubuntu on Digital Ocean, using these
[instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04?utm_source=digitalocean_marketplace_app_listing_page).

I am running into permissions issues whereby if I give these permissions
`sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/project/storage sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/project/bootstrap/cache`

I get access to my login page (though a 500 error on every other route), but I also get `The stream or file "/var/www/project/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied` whenever I try to run php artisan optimize, route:clear, etc.

If I set the permissions to this

`sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/project/storage sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/project/bootstrap/cache`

I get the opposite problem, wherein I can run artisan commands and write to the log, but no pages are accessible.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `chmod -R www-data.www-data /var/www/project` which sets the `group` and `owner`, you might also need to change the specific `dir` permissions.

```sh
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/project/storage/
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/project/bootstrap/cache
```

If you're trying to perform operations in your `/var/www/project` directory on the server, ensure that the `user` you are logged onto the server as is in the `www-data` group.

You can check the groups you're in simply by typing `groups` in your shell. If you don't see `www-data` in the list returned, add yourself.

```sh
usermod -aG www-data $USER
```

Once you've added yourself to the `www-data` group you will need to relog for the change to take effect.

Comment: This fixed my issue with permissions. Thank you! The 500 issue was caused because I'd forgot to run my migrations after deployment

Answer (score 0):

You need to change boostrap cache folder and laravel.log file into read, write, and execute. Go to your laravel project, and put this code

```
sudo chmod 777 bootstrap/cache/
sudo chmod 777 storage/logs/*.log
```